# SQL global search

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Is there in SQL something like a global search ?

I would like to perform a LIKE on all tables and all fields.

I am running MariaDB

Comment: Are you trying to find table/column names that match a pattern or are you trying to search the contents of fields?

Comment: simple answer is no and the complicated also yes (You need to query information_schema and build a queury for every table/column)